# One of Two New Sconces Not Working

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, light

I just replaced two sconces above my stairs. One of the sconces is working, but the other is not. I checked the connections and bulb, but nothing fixed it. So then I tried to reinstall the old fixture which had been working previously, and it also won't turn on.

The sconce that is working has two black, two white, and two ground wires in the electrical box. The one that's not working only has one of each. Both lights are on the same switch if that information adds anything to the troubleshooting. Any thoughts on what could be causing the sconce to not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recheck your connections,  The box with the 2 blacks, whites and grounds has the lead cable that brings power from the switch on one of the black wires. That is then transferred to the other sconce.  Your connections should be all blacks  together with a pigtail to the new sconce. All whites together with pigtail to the sconce and same with grounds. This will give you the Hot, neutral and ground you need at the second sconce.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem and saved us a bunch of money.

Answer (score 2):

Using a meter, check for voltage at the 2nd sconce that isn't working, if none, or very low phantom voltage, you need to check the other sconce for a connection problem.  From your question, this is recent work and it is most likely a bad connection in the working one. Black to black for installed wires and to the black wire to the sconce. Same with the white wires.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem and saved us a bunch of money.